# How to check if a signal is toggling after some time in simvision TCL command

Tags: tcl, waveform, cadence

I was working in simvision environment and I was developing to script to check whether a signal is toggling after some time. Could you please let me know if there are TCL command in the simvision console.

I was using `waveform values -at time signal` but it was displaying one value.